# How to get all category attribute Label

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

How to get all category attribute Label in magento admin I am using the below code but its returning only name i need to multiple values like description,name,id

```
$attributeModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('3', 'name');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($attributeModel->getData());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either one of the method:

**1st Method**

```
$categoryEntityTypeId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('catalog_category')->getId();
$attributesCollection = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_id', $categoryEntityTypeId);
foreach ($attributesCollection as $_attribute) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($_attribute->getFrontendLabel());
}
```

**2nd Method**

```
$attributesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_attribute_collection');
foreach ($attributesCollection as $_attribute) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($_attribute->getFrontendLabel());
}
```